# How to achieve a speed up by adding unit clauses to solve a sequence of CP-SAT problems incrementally?

Tags: performance, solver, or-tools, cp-sat

I am solving a sequence of SAT problems, where the next SAT problem can be always built incrementally by adding some unit clauses to the model of the previous SAT problem. Can we speed up CP-SAT  by not only reusing the constraints and variables in the previous SAT problem, but also reusing the intermediate results by solving previous SAT problem?

Does the following code work:

```
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

    x = model.NewBoolVar('x')
    y = model.NewBoolVar('y')

    model.AddBoolOr([x, y.Not()])

    # retrieve the results for the first problem
    status = solver.Solve(model)

    ....
    # add a new unit clause
    model.AddBoolOr([x.Not()])
    # retrieve the results for the second problem
    status = solver.Solve(model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called solution hinting.

See [this example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/model.md#python-code)

Comment: Thanks, Laurent. "Addhint" is useful, but the values are not added as hard constraints. It means that the next problem defined by the hard constraints may not be solved exactly via hinting, since the solver may revert the hints if it chooses to give up finding the solution following the hints.

Comment: then just add the constraints var == value one by one.

Comment: Is the SAT solver able to reuse part of the computation from the previous SAT problem (the problem without the new constraints)? For example, adding new constraints will only influence the values of some variables but not all. Then the SAT solver may still use the values of these uninfluenced variables, and save some computation.